# Customer managed key to encrypt Azure repos

Tags: azure, encryption, repository

for the source code in the Azure Repos, I know it is by default encrypted with Microsoft managed key.

But, does it support encryption by customer managed key?  If yes, how is it configured?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. This option is not available. As you stated, it is running on Azure and as such, the data is encrypted at rest using Microsoft keys.

I would recommend you to log this feature request on Azure DevOps Services user voice:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Thanks, LMG. I'll log a request.